# Dont count respectively vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity A is
  Port (
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        reset: in std_logic; -- reset input 
        counter: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000"-- output 4-bit counter
);
end A;

architecture Behavioral of A is
 signal counter_up: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
 signal countOf : integer := -1;
 signal count : integer := 0;
 signal temp : std_logic := '0';
begin
-- up counter

      process(clk)
     begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
count <=count+1;
if(count = 50000000) then
temp <= not temp;
count <=1;
end if;
end if;
end process;

process(temp,reset)
begin
if(reset = '1') then
    countOf <= 0;
 else
        if(temp = '1') then 

             if( countOf < 4) then countOf <= countOf + 1;
             else countOf <= 0; end if;

            if(countOf = 0) then counter_up <= "0000"; end if;
            if(countOf = 1) then counter_up <= "0001"; end if;
            if(countOf = 2) then counter_up <= "0010"; end if;
            if(countOf = 3) then counter_up <= "0100"; end if;
            if(countOf = 4) then counter_up <= "1000"; end if;


        end if;

 end if;
end process;

counter <= counter_up;

end Behavioral;
```

Hi I want to make a counter from 0 up to 4. As you see I divide my clock to 1 HZ and in the process of temp and reset, I assigned all conditions however it doesnt count how ı want. It is very weird . How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your combinatorial process will not work. Why not put everything into the clocked process? P.s. of you'd written a test bench, you would have already seen that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `process(temp, reset)` cannot work, because you made it combinatoric, which is not what you need in this instance. Works fine in simulation, doesn't work at all in hardware.

What you wrote generates a loop in hardware: The state of `countOf` is dependent on the state of `temp` **and** the state of `countOf` itself. Since your process contains no clock, the state of `countOf` changes as fast as gate delay allows it(if this code will be synthesized correctly at all).

If your software is any good, it'll give you a warning like this:

```
[Synth 8-614] signal 'countOf' is read in the process but is not in the sensitivity list
```

which you should **never** ignore, because in 99% of the cases, that means you'll get undesired behaviour and/or simulation mismatches.

What you need to do is make `temp` your clock. It is generated by a clock divider, so logically you almost certainly want it to be a clock as well. If you replace `if (temp = '1') then` with `if rising_edge(temp) then`, your code will work as desired.

Side note: Please remove `use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;` and `use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;`. Not only do you not need any unsigned library for your code at all, but `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH` is **deprecated and should no longer be used**. It has been for years. Use `IEEE.NUMERIC_STD` instead.